# Return Object with Greater Parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two images: `one` and `two`. I want to determine which is the biggest and smallest and assign them to `big` and `small` respectively. What is the cleanest and pythonic solution?

My solution is as follows:

```
one = Image.open(url)
two = Image.open(url)

big, small = (one, two) if one.width > two.width else (two, one)
```

Comment: That solution looks fine.

Comment: This questions is based on opinions, you might want to take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Thats being said, it's indeed a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a more pythonic approach, you could consider using the power of `sorted` to check which file is larger. Advantage of this is that it can easily be expanded to work for a list of images rather than just comparing two items.

```
images = [Image.open(url1), Image.open(url2), Image.open(url3)]

sorted_images = sorted(images, key=lambda img: img.width, reverse=True)
big, second_biggest = sorted_images[0:2]
```

The above example shows how you can use the `width` attribute of the class instances to sort the images from largest to smallest. `reverse=True` tells `sorted` to sort the items in largest-smallest order.
The final row just gets the largest two elements from the list and stores them in their own variables.